# Writing a wordpress plugin, trying to retrieve data from customized table?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a wordpress plugin. I had created a table and trying to retrieve data from the table but it give me an error message

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in
>   /home2/l2on708/public_html/mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php
>   on line 79 and defined in
>   /home2/l2on708/public_html/mysite.com/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line
>   1210

```
<?php
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "gallery_rating"; 


function options_page(){
    /*
    *  displaying back-end plugin page 
    */
    global $table_name;
    global $wpdb;


    $stmt = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ");  
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stm->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($rows as $rows) {

      $options_link = $rows['link'];
   }

   }


function table_install () {
      global $wpdb;
      global $table_name;


      $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

      $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        link varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        src varchar(250) NOT NULL,
        click int(11) NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE KEY id (id)
      ) $charset_collate;";

      require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
      dbDelta( $sql );
   }   
   // run the install scripts upon plugin activation
   register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'table_install');
?>
```

Comment: Read below post
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/php-warning-missing-argument-2-for-wpdb-prepare/

Answer (score 0):

As of WordPress 3.5, `wpdb::prepare()` enforces a **minimum of 2 arguments** (as the error tells you):

1. The query
2. A value to substitute into the placeholder.

More info can be found [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks).

That said, `prepare()` may not even be the correct method for you to be using in this case; you may be better off using something like [`get_results()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results).

Comment: Thanks for response. Will get_results() be a safer way for preventing injection?